# How to make all the childs of a Material Button ToggleGroup not clickable in kotlin

Tags: android, android-button, togglebutton, material-components-android, materialbutton

i have a lots of child buttons in a toggle group. And i want that whenever one of the child is clicked, make the whole toggle group not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **`OnButtonCheckedListener()`** listener:

```
    materialButtonToggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
        for (i in 0 until materialButtonToggleGroup.childCount) {
            materialButtonToggleGroup.getChildAt(i).isClickable = false
        }
    }
```